# Complex integral - Cauchy residue theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $a>0$. Determine the integral \begin{equation}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}dx\end{equation}

Attempt: Let the integrand be $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}$. Then asymptotically for large $x$ we have $f(x)\sim\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$ and we have that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2}dx$ converges, so our integral indeed converges.

Now, we have that the poles of our function are at $x=0,x=\pm ia$. I don't know how to deal with the pole/singularity at $x=0$ other than to treat the lower limit as $c\to 0$. Neglecting this singularity, close the contour in the upper half plane. The residue at $x=ia$ is $\frac{\ln(ia)}{2ia}$. So Cauchy's residue theorem gives us that the integral is $\frac{\pi\ln(ia)}{a}$.

Of course the issue here is that $\ln$ is undefined at $0$, and I cannot decide what other contour I should use.

Comment: I am giving you the indefinite integration of the same...put the limit yourselves and you can get the answer in a very simplistic way $$\dfrac{\mathrm{i}\left(\ln\left(-\mathrm{i}a\right)\ln\left(\left|x+\mathrm{i}a\right|\right)-\ln\left(\mathrm{i}a\right)\ln\left(\left|x-\mathrm{i}a\right|\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}x+a}{a}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{\mathrm{i}x-a}{a}\right)\right)}{2a}$$

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x$$Does not converge

Comment: and after putting limits you're getting $$\dfrac{{\pi}\ln\left(a\right)}{2a}$$ there is not $ia$...assuming that $a>0$

Comment: Hint: take $\Im\oint\frac{\ln^2zdz}{z^2+a^2}$ around a keyhole contour. You should find $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln z}{z^2+a^2}dz=\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln a$.

Answer (score 2):

To use contour integration, consider the integral along the keyhole contour which omits the real axis; i.e. let $\epsilon$ be a very small positive real, $R$ a very big real, and $\theta=\arcsin(\epsilon/R)$:
$$
\gamma=\left[i\epsilon,Re^{i\theta}\right]\cup Re^{i[\theta,2\pi-\theta]}\cup\left[Re^{-i\theta},-i\epsilon\right]\cup\epsilon e^{i[3\pi/2,\pi/2]}\tag1
$$
Then consider the integral
$$
\int_\gamma\frac{\log(z)^2}{z^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag2
$$
Since
$$
(\log(x)+2\pi i)^2=\log(x)^2+4\pi i\log(x)-4\pi^2\tag3
$$
the integral along the upper and lower sides of the real axis cancel except for $\frac{4\pi i\log(x)-4\pi^2}{x^2+a^2}$ extra on the lower side (whose contribution is negated since $\left[Re^{-i\theta},-i\epsilon\right]$ goes right to left).

The integral along the curved sections vanishes. On $Re^{i[\theta,2\pi-\theta]}$ the absolute value of the integral is bounded by $\frac{\log(R)^2+4\pi^2}{R^2}2\pi R\to0$ as $R\to\infty$. Furthermore, on $\epsilon e^{i[3\pi/2,\pi/2]}$ the absolute value of the integral is bounded by $\frac{\log(\epsilon)^2+4\pi^2}{a^2}\pi\epsilon\to0$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

[image]

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\frac{\log(z)^2}{z^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}z&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{4\pi i\log(x)-4\pi^2}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4a}\\
\scriptsize2\pi i\left(\frac{(\log(a)+\pi i/2)^2}{2ai}-\frac{(\log(a)+3\pi i/2)^2}{2ai}\right)&=-4\pi i\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x+4\pi^2\frac\pi{2a}\tag{4b}\\
\frac\pi{a}\left(-2\pi i\log(a)+2\pi^2\right)&=-4\pi i\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{2\pi^3}a\tag{4c}\\
\frac{\pi\log(a)}{2a}&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ account for the cancellation on the upper and lower sides of the real axis
$\phantom{\text{(4a):}}$ and the vanishing of the integral on the curved parts of the contour
$\text{(4b):}$ compute the residues on the left hand side
$\phantom{\text{(4b):}}$ and simplify the integrals on the right hand side
$\text{(4c):}$ simplify both sides
$\text{(4d):}$ cancel $\frac{2\pi^3}a$ from both sides
$\phantom{\text{(4d):}}$ then the factor of $-4\pi i$ from both sides

---

This integral does not require contour integration.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1a\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(a)+\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
&=\frac1a\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(a)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac1a\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5b}\\
&=\frac{\pi\log(a)}{2a}+0\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a):}$ substitute $x\mapsto ax$
$\text{(5b):}$ break the integral into two pieces
$\text{(5c):}$ the left hand integral is a simple arctangent
$\phantom{\text{(5c):}}$ the right hand integral is $0$ because it is equal to its negative by substituting $x\mapsto1/x$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with a true semicircle, which doesn't have to avoid the origin with a smaller arc that forms a "half-doughnut" contour. Your integral is $\lim_{b\to0^+}I(b)$ with$$I(b):=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+b^2)}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac14\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\ln(x^2+b^2)}{x^2+a^2}dx=\Re J(b),\,J(b):=\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\ln(x+ib)}{x^2+a^2}dx$$for $b>0$. By the residue theorem,$$J(b)=i\pi\lim_{z\to ia}\frac{\ln(z+ib)}{z+ia}=\frac{\pi}{2a}\left[\ln(a+b)+\frac{i\pi}{2}\right]\implies I(b)=\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln(a+b),$$making your integral $\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln a$ as in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

$z=0$ is not a pole; it is a branch point. The contour cannot contain nor pass through $z=0$. You can choose a semicircle in the upper half plane as contour, but then there must be an indent at the origin as in the image below:

[image: contour integral]

Let $\gamma$ be the small semicircle, and $\Gamma$ the large one. Also let their radii be $\epsilon$ and $R$ respectively. Then the integral of $f(z)=\ln(z)/(z^2+a^2)$ around the contour $C$ can be written as

$$\oint_Cf(z)dz = \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{\epsilon}^{R}f(z)dz+\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}f(z)dz$$

We are interested in the third term of the RHS in the case when $\epsilon \to 0$, $R \to \infty$. First, consider the integral over $\gamma$. Here, $z=\epsilon e^{i\theta} \implies dz=i\epsilon e^{i\theta} d\theta$, so

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^2+a^2} dz = \int_{\gamma} \frac{\ln(\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{\epsilon^2e^{2i\theta}+a^2} ie^{i\theta} d\theta \to 0 \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0$$

since $\lim_{x \to 0}x\ln(x)=0$. Second, consider the integral over $\Gamma$. Here, $z=Re^{i\theta}$, $0\leq \theta < \pi$, so

$$\left|\frac{\ln(z)}{z^2+a^2}\right| =  \frac{\left|\ln(Re^{i\theta})\right|}{\left|R^2e^{2i\theta}+a^2\right|} \leq \frac{\ln(R)}{R^2}$$

Using the estimation lemma and letting $R \to \infty$, we can see that

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\left|\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz\right| \leq \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{\ln(R)}{R^2} \cdot (\text{arc length of $\Gamma$}) = \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{\pi\ln(R)}{R} = 0$$

since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(x)/x=0$. Now, when $\epsilon \to 0$, the two remaining integrals on the real axis (where $z=x$, $dz=dx$) can be simplified to

\begin{aligned} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx + \int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2} dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx - \int_{0}^{-\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(-x)}{x^2+a^2}dx \\ &= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx + i\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx \\ \end{aligned}

because $\ln(-x)=\ln(x)+i\pi$. Lastly, the residue theorem says that

$$\oint_C f(z) dz = 2\pi i \cdot \text{(sum of all residues)}$$

In this case, the only pole that is enclosed by the contour is $z=ia$, so the residue is

$$Res_{z=ia}=\lim_{z\to ia}(z-ia)f(z)=\lim_{z \to ia}\frac{\ln(z)}{z+ia}=\frac{\ln(ia)}{2ia} = \frac{\ln(a)+i\pi/2}{2ia} = \frac{\pi}{4a} - \frac{i\ln(a)}{2a}$$

which you calculated correctly. Hence

$$\oint_C f(z) dz = 2\pi i\left[ \frac{\pi}{4a} - \frac{i\ln(a)}{2a} \right] = \frac{i\pi^2}{2a} + \frac{\pi\ln(a)}{a}$$

Thus, letting $\epsilon \to 0$, $R \to \infty$ in the first equation so that all of the above results can be inserted, you get

$$ \frac{i\pi^2}{2a} + \frac{\pi\ln(a)}{a} = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx + i\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx $$

Equating the real parts of the left and right hand side gives

$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx = \frac{\pi\ln(a)}{a}$$

or

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx = \frac{\pi\ln(a)}{2a}$$

Comment: No, it is not an essential singularity. It is a branch point. Very, very different.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, of course - thank you. I corrected my mistake.